# How to draw graph with TiKz?

Tags: plot, draw

Please, help me draw in latex.

[image]

Comment: what you try so far? do you have equations for curves?

Comment: Please visit this page http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Answer (score 6):

Believe me, it is more fun to do such things yourself.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (-3,0)--(7,0)node[below]{$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-2)--(0,5)node[left]{$y$};
\foreach \X in {1,...,5} \draw[-](\X,0.1)--(\X,-0.1)node[below]{$\X$};
\foreach \Y in {1,3,4} \draw[-](0.1,\Y)--(-0.1,\Y)node[left]{$\Y$};
\draw[blue] (1,1) circle (0.05) plot[variable=\x,domain=1:6.8]
({\x},{2-(\x-5)^2/16}); 
\draw[blue,fill=white] (5,2) circle (0.05) node[anchor=south east]{$y=g(x)$};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] (5,1) circle (0.05);
\draw[blue]  plot[variable=\x,domain=-2:2]
({\x},{3-(\x-2)^2/6}); 
\draw[blue,fill=white] (2,3) circle (0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]